# Inserting multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, comparative-review, stored-procedure

I am building a store. When a user decides to make a purchase I need to store it in the database, but since the purchase might be of more than 1 item I'm wondering which way is the best to insert multiple rows, here are my 3 options.

I use a database object that combines PDO with PDOStatement, which is why I don't define `$stmt` anywhere.

The input is:

```
$input = array(
    'user_id' => 15,
    'food_id' => 2,
    'quantity' => 15
);
```

The table I'm inserting into:

```
 CREATE TABLE `users_foods` (
 `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `food_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

## Option one

```
$insert_data = array();

while($input['quantity']){
    $insert_data[] = array($input['user_id'], $input['food_id']);
    $input['quantity']--;
}

$db->insert('users_foods', array('user_id', 'food_id'), $insert_data);
```

Respectively used functions are

```
public function insert($table, array $columns, array $values){
    $valArr = array();
    $data = array();

    $id = 0;
    if(!empty($values)){
        if(is_array($values[0])){
            foreach($values as $k => $v){
                foreach($v as $key => $val){
                    $data[':i'.$id] = $val;
                    $v[$key] = ':i'.$id;
                    $id++;
                }
                $valArr[] = '('.join(',', $v).')';
            }
        }else{
            foreach($values as $key => $val){
                $data[':i'.$id] = $val;
                $v[$key] = ':i'.$id;
                $id++;
            }
            $valArr[] = '('.join(',', $v).')';
        }
    }

    return $this->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.join(',', $columns).') VALUES '.join(',', $valArr))->execute($data);
}

private function parseWhereClause(array $where, $iteration = 0, $id = 0, $sd = null){
    $sql = array();
    $data = array();

    if(count($where) == 3 && !is_array(reset($where))){
        if(is_array($where[2])){
            foreach($where[2] as $expr){
                $sql[] = ':w'.$iteration.$id;
                $data[':w'.$iteration.$id++] = $expr;
            }
            switch(strtolower($where[1])){
                case 'in': $sql = $where[0] . ' ' . $where[1] . ' ('.join(',', $sql).')'; break;
                case 'between': $sql = $where[0] . ' ' . $where[1] . ' '.join(' AND ', $sql); break;
            }
        }else{
            $sql = $where[0] . ' ' . $where[1] . ' :w'.$iteration.$id;
            $data[':w'.$iteration.$id] = $where[2];
        }
    }else{
        if(!empty($where)){
            $id = 0;

            foreach($where as $c => $expressions){
                $recur = $this->parseWhereClause($expressions, ++$iteration, $id++, $c);
                $sql[] = $recur['sql'];
                $data += $recur['data'];
            }

            $sql = '('.join(' '.$sd.' ', $sql).')';
        }else{
            $sql = '1';
        }
    }

    return array(
        'sql' => $sql,
        'data' => $data
    );
}
```

This method will only run one large query.

## Option two

```
$db->prepare('INSERT INTO users_foods (user_id, food_id) VALUES (?, ?)');

while($input['quantity']){
    $db->execute(array($input['user_id'], $input['food_id']));
    $input['quantity']--;
}
```

not quite sure how this prepare-execute thing works under the hood though, but I believe that this will run 15 queries (because quantity is 15 in the example).

## Option three

**MySQL**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `buy_food`(IN `user_id` INT UNSIGNED, IN `food_id` INT UNSIGNED, IN `quantity` INT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN

 WHILE quantity > 0 DO
   INSERT INTO users_foods (`user_id`, `food_id`) VALUES (user_id, food_id);
   SET quantity = quantity - 1;
 END WHILE;

END
```

**PHP**

```
$db->prepare('CALL buy_food(?, ?, ?)')->execute(array(

    $input['user_id'], 
    $input['food_id'], 
    $input['quantity']

));
```

Which one do you think is the best way to go and why?

Comment: I think you will get primarily opinion-based answers as every programmer you ask will have their own preference.

Comment: Assuming `$db` is an instance of a wrapper around `PDO`: **Get rid of it**: You're calling `$db->prepare`, which suggests it's an instance of `PDO`, but you're also calling `$db->execute`, which is a method of `PDOStatement`. That's just awful. Aslo: a `PDOStatement` has a method `closeCursor`, meant to be used in case of multiple `INSERT` queries

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem You don't have to assume it, I described what `$db` is in the PS. Why would you suggest that is "awful". I think it is pretty handy, saving me a lot of lines. I can always call `getStmt()` and return the `PDOStatement` object when I need it.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: Quite apart from my profound [aversion of PDO wrappers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29362/very-simple-php-pdo-class/29394#29394), having an object that does two jobs (conencting to `PDO` and fetching results through `PDOStatement`) violates the SRP, it also makes it hard to re-use a statement safely (I could be fetching results from X, processing them, and inserting them in Y, requiring at least 2 statements). You can never reliably call `closeCursor` or be sure the statement is not referenced anywhere.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem You may wish to continue discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a maxim in computer science that there are really "only three numbers": *zero, one, and many*.  You have a case of *many*, and you should treat it as such.  Otherwise, someday a customer might want to buy a hundred of some food item, and performance will be poor.

Therefore, I recommend…

### Option four

Instead of having the table represent current supply levels, keep a transaction log, where the `quantity` column stores purchases as positive values and consumption as negative values.

```
INSERT INTO user_food_purchase (user_id, food_id, quantity) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

Then, adjust the rest of your application to accommodate the schema change.  For compatibility, you could define a view:

```
CREATE VIEW user_food AS
SELECT user_id, food_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
    FROM user_food_purchase
    GROUP BY user_id, food_id;
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow :/

Comment: Insert just one row per transaction. (If you withdraw $47 from your bank account, the bank doesn't record that as 47 one-dollar withdrawal records, does it?)

Comment: I totally agree, this is the best way to go.

Comment: Now I see. It used to be like this but then handling quantity became really sloppy. For example when a user does something with food with id 2, I have to update the table and reduce quantity, then if it's 0 I have to delete the row and this is just not giving me the feeling of clean coding. As opposed to now - 1 row = 1 in quantity, when used I simply delete with limit 1 and I'm done, all flows easily. I think the example with the bank is a little misleading

Comment: And the same with inserting, I have to do REPLACE instead of INSERT which would delete the entire row and create it again which is needless operations in the long run and a slow down in performance because HDD operations..

Comment: You may wish to continue discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Comment: It looks to me that data should represent current state only. Why bother with transaction log (and it's further maintenance)?

Comment: @200_success, Unheard of... What kind of maxim is this?

Answer (score 6):

> I am building a store. When a user decides to make a purchase I need to store it in the database but since the purchase might be of more than 1 item I'm wondering which way is the best to insert multiple rows, here are my 3 options.

Who said you had to insert multiple rows?

If I buy 10 apples, that's one row: `user_id = 42, food_id = 103, quantity = 10`.

## Option one

You are creating a method to produce a very long SQL statement. This makes it very very very hard to follow. Avoid such methods! It will make it very confusing for Mr. Maintainer to understand what it actually does. Additionally, you are not using parametrized SQL correctly (which would be even more complicated, although possible, to use there). Just because you prepare a statement doesn't make it safe.

A concatenated prepared SQL statement is just as dangerous as a non-prepared one. It is the parametrization that can make it safe(r). It is hard to tell for me if this version is *really* vulnerable to SQL, because it is hard to keep track of all the concatenations. Either way, this is the worst in my opinion.

## Option one and two

If `quantity` is negative, these loops will never end.

## Option three

Sure, this one would work fine as it is now I guess. However, this is not right as Option four (introduced by 200_success) is much better. And in my opinion, it would be overkill to use a SQL procedure for this (others might disagree).

---

I think currently, option two is the best, but it is doing the wrong thing.

Loop through all the kinds of items I am buying instead of looping over all the 10 apples.

It is much easier (requires less computing power and less work by the database) to loop over an array of `(apples, pears, bananas)` (3 times) than to loop 10 times for apples, 7 times for pears, and 30 times for bananas. *<sub>(I like bananas, OK? And I do plan to share some...)</sub>*

Comment: I'm not quite an expert on databases, or anything really, but isn't that violating database normalization rules :?

Comment: Your current schema violates database normalization even more. Suppose that a user has five apples, represented by five identical rows in the table. After consuming one apple, you would have to pick exactly one of the five identical rows representing apples to be deleted, which is an unusual operation to do.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Actually, I would say that when you can have multiple *identical* rows in your database, **that** is violating database normalization.