# Database wrapper class

Tags: php, mysql, php5

I'm trying to create a single class to interact with my database (MariaDB, in this case). Is there anything I can do to improve this code? I'm fairly new to Object-oriented PHP.

```
<?php
namespace TOB\Model;

use \TOB\Utility as U;

abstract class CRUDD {
    protected $table_name = "";
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        if (is_int($data)) {
            $this->read($data);
        } else if (is_string($data)) {
            $this->read($data, true);
        } else if (is_array($data)) {
            $this->create($data);
        } else {
            U\Error::report("Cannot determine course of action for '" . $this->table_name . "' in CRUDD.", 1);
        }
    }
    public function create($data)
    {
        /*
            Create an object and store it in the database.
        */
        $query = "INSERT INTO `" . $this->table_name . "` (";
        foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
            $fields[] = $field;
            $values[] = $value;
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++) {
            if ($i == (count($fields) - 1)) {
                $query .= "`" . $fields[$i] . "`";
            } else {
                $query .= "`" . $fields[$i] . "`, ";
            }
        }
        $query .= ") VALUES (";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
            if ($i == (count($values) - 1)) {
                $query .= "?";
            } else {
                $query .= "?, ";
            }
        }
        $query .= ");";
        $query = $mysql->handle->prepare($query);
        $this->read((int)$mysql->handle->lastInsertId());
        if ($query = $query->execute($values)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function read($data, $use_string = false)
    {
        /*
            Read an object from the database.
        */
        $mysql = new U\MySQL();
        if ($use_string) {
            $query_string = "SELECT * FROM `" . $this->table_name . "` WHERE `" . $this->table_name . "_link` = ? LIMIT 1;";
            if ($query = $mysql->handle->prepare($query_string)) {
                $query->bindParam(1, $data, \PDO::PARAM_STR, 32);
            } else {
                U\Error::report("Could not prepare statement '" . $query_string . "' in CRUDD.", 2);
            }
        } else {
            $query_string = "SELECT * FROM `" . $this->table_name . "` WHERE `" . $this->table_name . "_id` = ? LIMIT 1;";
            if ($query = $mysql->handle->prepare($query_string)) {
                $query->bindParam(1, $data, \PDO::PARAM_INT, 32);
            } else {
                U\Error::report("Could not prepare statement '" . $query_string . "' in CRUDD.", 2);
            }
        }
        $query->execute();
        if ($query->rowCount() >= 1) {
            foreach($query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $key => $value) {
                if (substr($key, 0, (strlen($this->table_name) + 1)) == $this->table_name . "_") {
                    $key2 = substr($key, (strlen($this->table_name) + 1));
                    $this->$key2 = $value;
                } else {
                    $this->$key = $value;
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $key => $value) {
                if ($key != "table_name") {
                    unset($this->$key); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public function update($field_name = null)
    {
        /*
            Update some or all of an object.
        */
        if (is_null($field_name)) {
            $mysql = new \Utility\MySQL();
            $query = "UPDATE `" . $this->table_name . "` SET ";
            foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $field => $value) {
                if (($field != "class_name") && ((substr($field, 0, strlen($this->table_name)) == $this->table_name) || ($field == "id"))) {
                    $fields[] = $field;
                    $values[] = $value;
                }
            }
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++) {
                if ($fields[$i] == "id") {
                    $fields[$i] = "" . $this->table_name . "_id";   
                }
                if ($i == (count($fields) - 1)) {
                    $query .= "`" . $fields[$i] . "` = ?";
                } else {
                    $query .= "`" . $fields[$i] . "` = ?, ";
                }
            }
            $query .= " WHERE `" . $this->table_name . "_id` = " . $this->id;
            $query = $mysql->handle->prepare($query);
            $query = $query->execute($values);
            $this->read($this->id, false);
        } else if (is_array($field_name)) {
            // Able to update a set of values only
        } else {
            // Able to update a single value
        }
    }
    public function delete()
    {
        /*
            Make an object unreadable by marking it as deleted. This is a clean delete.
        */
        $mysql = new \Utility\MySQL();
        $query = "UPDATE `" . $this->table_name . "` SET `" . $this->table_name . "_deleted` = 1 WHERE `" . $this->table_name . "_id` = " . $this->id . ";";
        $query = $mysql->handle->prepare($query);
        $query = $query->execute();
        $this->read($this->id, false);
    }
    public function destroy()
    {
        /*
            Remove an object from the database altogether. This is a 'messy' delete.
        */
        $mysql = new \Utility\MySQL();
        $query = "DELETE FROM `" . $this->table_name . "` WHERE `" . $this->table_name . "_id` = " . $this->id . ";";
        $query = $mysql->handle->prepare($query);
        $query = $query->execute();
        $this->read($this->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are errors in your code (eg the `create`  method uses an undefined variable `$mysql` as though it were an object). Please note that this site only concerns actual, working code. Also look into dependency injection, and [read this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29362/very-simple-php-pdo-class/29394#29394) to learn why it applies to your code

Comment: Thanks, a very informative answer you linked to. How would I handle the PDO without using a MySQL class here. I've been warned against "global $pdo" in each function.

Comment: Either pass a PDO connection to the constructor (`public function __construct(PDO $db)`), or create the connection in a service, and pass data models to that service, which acts as a primitive mapper/data provider. That's a lot cleaner in terms of separation of concern at least

Answer (score 1):

#### Create method

Perhaps the `create` method should ensure `$data` is not empty - otherwise it could lead to SQL errors. Throwing an exception may be prudent.

Also in that method the loop to add field names could be simplified using the [`implode()` function](https://php.net/implode). If the first loop was updated so the field names were wrapped in backticks:

```
    foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
        $fields[] = "`$field`";
        $values[] = $value;
    }
```

Then the subsequent `for` loop:

> ```
>    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++) {
>         if ($i == (count($fields) - 1)) {
>             $query .= "`" . $fields[$i] . "`";
>         } else {
>             $query .= "`" . $fields[$i] . "`, ";
>         }
>     }
> ```

Can be replaced with this:

```
 $query .= implode(', ', $fields);
```

And similarly the list of placeholders can be created with [`array_fill()`](https://php.net/array_fill)

```
$placeholders = array_fill(0, count($values), '?');
$query .= ") VALUES (" . implode(', ', $placeholders) . ");";
```

#### Comments

Most of the methods appear to have a multi-line comment within the method describing what the method does. A common convention in many Object-Oriented languages is to have such a comment appear just above the method definition. While it isn't finalized this is described in the draft for the PHP Standards Recommendation [PSR-5 PHPDoc](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md). The DocBlock can also provide information about parameters, return values, exceptions that may be thrown, etc. Many IDEs will index those docblocks and use them to offer suggestions during development.

#### Undefined Variable

As was mentioned in a comment, the variable `$mysql` does not appear to be defined in the `create` method:

> ```
> $query = $mysql->handle->prepare($query);
> ```

Even if it was defined, `$query` gets assigned to the return value from calling the `prepare` method, so it starts as a string and then presumably contains a prepared statement. To avoid confusion for anyone reading the code (including your future self) it would be better to use a different variable  for the prepared statement - for example- if there was a need to utilize the string representing the query.

#### Variable overwriting

At the end of that `create` method are these lines:

> ```
>     if ($query = $query->execute($values)) {
>         return true;
>     }
> ```

It appears that `$query` gets re-assigned to the return value from the call to `execute()`. Again the variable gets overwritten, possible with a different type. This may lead to confusion if `$query` was used after these lines however there seems to be no point in assigning that value since `$query` is not used after that point.

#### Soft Deletion

It appears that the `delete()` method updates a deleted column, which is a technique for soft deletion. Should the `read()` method ensure that the value in the column is not `1`?